# How to automatically click a confirm box?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, confirm

My script clicks an image on a site. The image has an anchor `href` and an `onclick` `href`, but the onclick href has a confirm box that pops up once it's clicked.
The onclick HTML is:

```
onClick="this.href='link2';if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) { return false; }
```

How do I get the script to click ***OK*** in that confirm box, once it pops up?

I'm using this function to click the picture link:

```
function click(elm) {
 var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
 evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
 elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
click(picture element)
```

Comment: show us your script ! so we can help you

Comment: Link to the target page.  This question is currently way too vague for us to be able to answer.

Comment: why are you popping out the confirm box when you dont want user confirmation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can override the `confirm` method to temporarily silence it and return `true`. Below example will silence a confirm dialog only once, and only if it's called. Once the silenced dialog is executed, it will restore its original functionality and subsequent call to `confirm` method will work as normal.

```
var realConfirm=window.confirm;
window.confirm=function(){
  window.confirm=realConfirm;
  return true;
};
click(picture element);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You saved lots of my effort. I didn't think that it can be override...

Comment: Did you add these two lines `var realConfirm=window.confirm;` and `window.confirm=realConfirm;` to make it only dismiss one alert/confirm notification? Because just returning true to the alert works fine and kills all future alerts: `alert = function () {
        return true;
    }` Or even a one liner like this `alert = true;` Although the one liner gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: alert is not a function` @Jay