# Horseman.js -> handling window.confirm

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

I need help with a problem I'm facing, and am sure [node-horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman) can handle it.

I'm trying to accept a "window.confirm" alert and tried many things without success. Basically, after clicking on a button, I want to be able to "accept" the confirm message using horseman.

Going through the docs, I found this:

> .at(event, callback)
>   Respond to page events with the callback.

```
.at('confirm', function(msg) {
    return msg === 'Like this?' ? true : false;
})
```

Nevertheless, when I put the .at like this, before any *.open*

```
horseman
    .at('confirm', function(msg) {
        return msg === 'Do you accept?' ? true : false;
    })
```

I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: horseman.at is not a function
```

What I'm looking for: a way to accept a *window.confirm* using node-horseman.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570868/how-to-automatically-click-a-confirm-box) helped me solve the issue.

Instead of using ***.at*** I did the following:

```
horseman
    .open(myUrl)
    .evaluate(function(){
        var realConfirm=window.confirm;  
        // override the window.confirm function just once
        window.confirm=function(msg){
            window.confirm = realConfirm;
            if (msg=="message I am Expecting"){  
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        };
    })
    .click('#mybutton')
```

And this worked!

Basically, I override the window.confirm function for the next time it is called, and restore it to the previous value during the execution.

I hope this will help others as well.